# Python Selenium is redirecting the URL to another page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=aCT4Xpu4C-XYz7sPoI620Aw&q=site%3Arocketreach.co+Stephanie+Gentile+AxisPoint+Health&oq=site%3Arocketreach.co+Stephanie+Gentile+AxisPoint+Health&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQA1CXD1iOEmCgEmgAcAB4AIABAIgBAJIBAJgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwibjJvM3aPqAhVl7HMBHSCHDcoQ4dUDCAc&uact=5') 

results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="r"]/a/h3')  
results[0].click() #Clicking on the first google search
time.sleep(20)

results1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="blur-container"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/h3/a')  #click on the company name
results1[0].click() #click on the company name
time.sleep(20)

results2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="blur-container"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]/a')  
results2[0].click() #Clicking on Email Format
time.sleep(20)
```

What's happening is I want to open -> https://rocketreach.co/axispoint-health-email-format_b556823ff6d298ea and scrape the possible email addresses of the company

it is redirecting to this link -> https://rocketreach.co/?tags=!((incexc:include,keyword:%27AxisPoint%20Health%27,type:keywords))&start=1&page_size=10&mode=default

Any solution so that it opens the desired link not the redirected one?

Comment: Your google search leads to a person working at AxisPoint, but you want to end at Molina Healthcare. Is your first google seach really the right person?

Comment: Apologies for that, I was checking for another element in the data frame. I've updated the link that I want to open. Thanks

Comment: If i run your code (with time.sleep(5)), i will end here: https://rocketreach.co/axispoint-health-email-format_b556823ff6d298ea. So basically your code seems to work

Comment: It seemed to be working for me fine till the day before yesterday. Is it the website that is redirecting me to the other link?

Comment: Hm.. At what point does it redirect you? Like at the very first click after google or the last click?

Comment: It's redirecting me after clicking on the company name on some instances, and on the remaining instances, it's redirecting me after ending up here: rocketreach.co/axispoint-health-email-format_b556823ff6d298ea . And when it does redirect, it happens immediately, without waiting for time.sleep(20) condition. This is something quite unusual which I've never encountered before.

Comment: I do not know this kind of problem neither, sorry. Maybe it is worth to do some very basic things like clear the browser cache, restart the Computer, etc.